# How to give relative path in a executable jar?

Tags: java, spring, deployment, jar, path

I have a Spring app that I am deploying as a .jar.

The app has to write to a folder located in /src (precisely `/src/main/resources/patches`). I have this path directly in the code.

In application.properties: `PATCH_DIR = src/main/resources/patches`

The app has to also read a json file from `src/main/resources/myJson.json`, the path also being directly written in the code.

Prior to deploying, while running from the IDE everything goes well, the app sees the file and the folder and reads and writes correctly.

After building the .jar the paths change, the file is located in `myJar.jar/BOOT-if/classes/myJson.json` and the folder is respectively in `myJar.jar/BOOT-if/classes/patches`.

How can I specify these paths in the code in a way that even after building the jar they stay relevant to my application?

---

Edit: I can specify the path of the file as: `PatchApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource("myJson.json").getPath();`

This should solve the problem, as the path is relative to the class and not to the root of the project, but it does not improve anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a path in your file system,instead of the path inside a .jar.When you run your app ,it would access the given path.

Comment: this solution would not be suitable as I could deploy the jar on different machines having different folder structures

Comment: Generally,we store files in specific file system like hdfs,GridFs by integrating 
 their access driver in java.

Comment: that would be too much for my project

Answer (score 0):

generally all the classes goes to **classes** folder in jar.

all the classes ending after src/main/java goes to /classes/ folder
and similarly all the resources file
Eg. your source folder have src/main/java/com/mypack/ABC.java than you will find this in jar as  /classes/com/mypack/ABC.class .

**Try using /classes/patches and /classes/myJson.json.**

This should work

Comment: this means that I won't be able to test my app prior to building the jar

Comment: you can.Try writing a Unit test  or main method and provide the absolute path accordingly.

Comment: If Still your problem not resolve than try getting resource path using Example.class.getResource( "myJson.json" ). this will return you URL.